# Kendo MVC Server Side Paging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display a grid using Kendo and want to add server side paging. This is how my view looks like

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.Employee>()
        .Name("empGrid")
        .Columns(column =>
        {
            column.Bound(emp => emp.Tickets).Title("Tickets").Filterable(false).Sortable(false)
                .ClientTemplate("<div style='display:flex;align-items:center;'> " +
                                " #= getLateTicketIcon(DueDate) # " 
                                "</div>").Width(100);
            column.Bound(emp => emp.EmpID).Hidden();
            column.Bound(emp => emp.DeptID).Hidden();
            column.Bound(emp => emp.Name).Title("Name#").Width(100);
            column.Bound(emp => emp.TicketNumber).Width(150).ClientTemplate("#= getEempTickets(EmpID, DeptID) # ");
            column.Bound(emp => emp.DueDate).Width(150)
                .ClientTemplate("#: DueDate === null ? '' : kendo.toString(getDateAsUTC(kendo.parseDate(DueDate)), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #");
        })       
        .NoRecords("There are no records to display")
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Height("auto"))
        .Pageable(pager => pager
            .PageSizes(new[] { 10, 25, 50, 100, 200 })
            .Refresh(true)
            .Input(true))
        .Filterable()
        .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Columns(true))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Excel(ex =>
        {
            ex.AllPages(true);
            ex.Filterable(true);
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(50)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetTickets", "Employee").Data("readFromServerWithParameters").Type(HttpVerbs.Get)))
        .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("currentGridDataBound"))
        .AutoBind(false))
```

and the controller looks like, the problem I'm facing is what ever the page number I select on UI, the page number is always 1.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult GetTickets([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, long? empID,  string[] searchOptions)
        {
            List<Employee> results = repo.GetTickets(empID, searchOptions,request.Page,request.PageSize);
            JsonResult resultJson = Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            resultJson.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return resultJson;
        }
```

Comment: Would you be able to post a screenshot of the grid? This would help others better understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are paging the data twice, once in the GetTickets method (because page and page size are passed as parameters) and again in ToDataSourceResult. As a result, the ToDataSourceResult thinks that the whole set of data is a single page and returns an object where the total is equal to the page size.

To avoid this, either expose a method from your repo that returns the whole set of data

e.g.

```
        public IQueryable<T> GetAllTickets(int empID)
        {
            return this.dbSet.Where(x=> x.id === empID);
        }
```

Then use the method in the action as follows:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult GetTickets([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, long? empID,  string[] searchOptions)
        {
            List<Employee> results = repo.GetAllTickets(empID);
            JsonResult resultJson = Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            resultJson.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return resultJson;
        }
```

Another option would be to skip calling the ToDataSourceResult method and create the DataSourceResult instance yourself.

e.g.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
        public ActionResult GetTickets([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, long? empID,  string[] searchOptions)
        {
            List<Employee> results = repo.GetTickets(empID, searchOptions,request.Page,request.PageSize);
            JsonResult resultJson = Json(new DataSourceResult {
                 Data = results,
                 Total = results.Count(),
                 ...
             }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            resultJson.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return resultJson;
        }
```

I wouldn't recommend the second option as you will have to handle the rest of the operations like sorting, grouping, filtering and aggregating yourself, while the TodataSourceResult will do it for you.